# Using holoeverywhere and Appcompat library together to show Activity Animations?

Tags: android

I am using Holoeverywhere library in my app. I was trying to implement some animation when a new activity is started. The following is the code for it. )

```
ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(WordListActivity.this,
                    R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left).toBundle();
```

But this code works only on higher apis. I found out that I can make use of ActivityOptionsCompat(), for which I need to add the Android app-compat v7 library.

When I add the app-compat v7 library to my app (which already makes use of holoeverywhere library), I get all sorts of "R cannot be resolved error". The errors go away when the appcompat lib is removed. I have had very difficult times with this error and would prefer not like to make lots of changes for appcompat library now.

My queries are:

1. Is it possible to make use of both holoeverywhere and appcompat library together and whether it is ok to do so?
2. Any other easier method to add activity animations like the code above for lower apis (8+)

P.S.: I am using eclipse

Comment: I'm using holoeverywhere and compat successfully with this: overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in_quick, R.anim.fade_out_quick); I just run this line when an activity is about to be finished or started. It also works on API 8+. Read the docs for overridePendingTransition to see how it should be used exactly.

Comment: @talkol, Thanks. I tried using this. But that is not working either. I have posted a separate question on SO for that
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119122/custom-activity-transition-animation-in-android

Comment: I saw in your other question that you've managed to get it working. I'll add an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you implement activity transition animations with `Activity.overridePendingTransition(..)`

This is available on API 5+, so it should work fine on API 8. I'm using it successfully with holoeverywhere and the compat lib.

**Usage:** call `overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);` right after `startActivity(Intent)` or `finish()` and it will override the next immediate transition.

**Note:** Make sure animations aren't disabled in your phone settings. If this is the case, activity transition animations will not be shown.