# custom activity transition animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

The current flow of my app is  Activity A -> Activity B ->Fragment B
I am trying to implement Activity transition animation. I have read many posts on SO mentioning about using overridependingtransition() and I have implemented almost everything mentioned in these posts. Somehow the animation is not working.

I need this to work on Android 2.2 i.e. sdkversion 8

This is the code:

```
Activity A 
oncreate method

Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, WordDetailActivity.class);
            detailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            detailIntent.putExtra(DbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
                startActivity(detailIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);


 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    }


Activity B

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    }
```

It would be great if someone could also suggest me any alternative way to implement activity transitions upto android 2.2

Comment: Just wondered if you know that phones that have their animation disabled in the phone settings wont show the activity transition animations... so don't count on it.

Comment: that was the issue. Thanks a lot!! Anyway to change the settings through my app, so that animations are visible on everyphone.
Or any other way to show transition animations?

Comment: @roiberg please add your comment as an answer as it seems to solve the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phones that have their animation disabled in the phone settings wont show the activity transition animations... so don't count on it.

Also, you can't change these users settings.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing it `onPause()` do in `onResume()`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}
```

and try using `minSdk="5"

**EDIT**

Try like this

```
Activity_A.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

Activity_B.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

**EDIT 2**

```
@Override
public void overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim) {
    super.overridePendingTransition(enterAnim, exitAnim);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In overridePendingTransition");
}
```

Check if this log is hit or not, because we don't know weather this method is called or not?(Place it inside both the A and B)

Also please remove  `detailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);` falg
and if its hit then replace `super.overridePendingTransition(enterAnim, exitAnim);` with `super.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);`

Comment: Should I do this in Activity A or B or in both?
My minSdk is 8. Would this not work?

Comment: Why have you used  `detailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);`???. Try removing that flag

Comment: was just trying out different things. removing that also does not help

Comment: that didn't help as well.

Comment: the animation in my phone was disabled. Check out the comment from roiberg above. Am looking for how to enable it programmatically, in case you have an idea..Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok!!!, Here something i found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443942/how-can-i-turn-on-animation-programatically and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936946/disable-window-and-transition-settings but i am not sure it will work, Anyway Best of Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

No need to write anywhere else except after startActivity.
write like this.

```
 Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, WordDetailActivity.class);

 detailIntent.putExtra(DbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
   startActivity(detailIntent);
 this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //annination indside fragment to translate fragment

      getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_right,
                    R.animator.slide_in_left_out,     
                                            R.animator.slide_in_left,
                    R.animator.slide_in_right_out)
            .replace(R.id.linearlayout, new mFragment())
            .addToBackStack("fragments")
            .commit();

  // add inside activity to translate activity

 Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AbcActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_in,
                    R.anim.slide_left_out);

  // put this inside OnBackPressed 
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_right_out);
```