# Change layout transition on android apps?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, transition

How to change layout(activity) incoming/outgoing transition animation?
I want my main layout starts with a fade-in-form-white animation How should I perform this?
It is a basic Question I think, but I cant find a proper answer anywhere on the net!

Comment: check out this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119122/custom-activity-transition-animation-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Check out the animations [document on developers.android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html) ... I guess you could declare the fade in and fade out animations with the `alpha()` properties and since you are doing custom animations on activity do not forget to declare the `overridePendingTransition(0,0)` on intent fire.