# How to animate an then finish a Dialog Activity on pressing back button in android?

Tags: android, dialog, android-animation, onkeydown

I have done the following.

On moving from `cart_activity` which is an `Activity` to another `Dialog Activity` name `Order_Confrim_Dialog` I am using a bottom to top animation.

What I am trying to do is on pressing the `keydown` button I want to animate the `Dialog Activity`. But the `keydown` or '`back` button simply closes the dialog activity without any animation. Can anyone correct my code? My code is as folllows:

cart_activity.java

```
        Intent intDialog = new Intent(cart_activity.this, Order_Confrim_Dialog.class);
        startActivity(intDialog);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_dialog, R.anim.slide_out_down);
```

Order_Confirm_Dialog.java

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // super.onBackPressed();
    Order_Confrim_Dialog.this.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.close_down_dialog, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but have you tried switching the 2 code lines in onBackPressed() ? you do finish before you do the animation

Comment: Order_Confrim_Dialog.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.close_down_dialog, 0); then call finish();

Comment: or you should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119122/custom-activity-transition-animation-in-android. Perhaps the 0 in overridePendingTransition might be the issue, you might need an animation for R.anim.open_activity

Answer (score 0):

there has to be an issue with, `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.close_down_dialog, 0);`
Can you provide the anim file.
To test it just place this

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_dialog, R.anim.slide_out_down);
```

in that place there will be a wrong animation but at least you can know.